# How to reduce the amount of hooks in a React component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a big component, inside I have 4 subcomponents, each 4 subcomponents have a couple of components each. Only two levels of components, but I still pass a lot of props and handlers and I have all the state in the top component:

```
const MyBigComp = () => {
  const [a, setA] = useState(false);
  const [b, setB] = useState([]);
  const [c, setC] = useState(0);
  const [d, setD] = useState(true);
  const [e, setE] = useState({ f: [], g: [] });
  // I have ~20 more useState hooks in here.

  // Then I have a lot of handlers:

  const toggleX = () => {
    setA(prev => !prev);
  }

  const addY = () => {
    setB(prev => ([...prev, { z: 1 }]));
  }

  // And I have more useEffects and other handlers in here also.

  return (
    <Comp1 a={a} toggleX={toggleX} /> // For simplicity I only pass two props but in reality there are like 10-12 props for each component.
    <Comp2 b={b} addY={addY} />
    <Comp3 c={c} toggleX={toggleX} />
    <Comp4 d={d} e={e} addY={addY} />
  );
}
```

My first thought would be to lower the state whenever possible, but every piece of state needs to be in the parent component because it's used by a handler or shared to other components.

I thought of using Context but I don't know if it's the best solution here since prop drilling is not much of an issue since it's only two levels down.

Comment: You can simply make them in a composite single state. (If they are related to each other)

Comment: Context is fine regardless of how many levels it is. The point of context is to simplify your components and limit passing states around, and if it achieves that, then go for it.

Answer (score 3):

This sounds like a case for [`useReducer`](https://beta.reactjs.org/reference/react/useReducer), which is an ergonomic way of dealing with complex state management in a single state object.

Your code looks like it could be modeled roughly like this:

```
function reducer(state, action) {
  switch (action.type) {
    case 'toggle': {
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.field]: !state[action.field]
      };
    }
    case 'set': {
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.field]: action.value
      };
    }}
    case 'add': {
      return {
        ...state,
        [action.field]: [...state[action.field], action.value]
      };
    }
  }
  throw Error('Unknown action: ' + action.type);
}
```

Which you can then use like this:

```
  const [state, dispatch] = useReducer(reducer, { initialStateHere });
  
  function handleToggle() {
    dispatch({ type: 'toggle', field: "abc" });
  }

  function handleInputChange(e) {
    dispatch({
      type: 'add',
      field: 'myList',
      value: "my new todo"
    });
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit difficult to say what is the best option to you case because the context that you gave is too short, but I think you just need to use react's ContextApi to reduce the amout of the useStates and avoid prop drilling.

StoreContext.js:

```
import { createContext } from "react";
export const StoreContext = createContext(null);
```

App.jsx:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import { StoreContext } from "./StoreContext";
import MyBigComp from "./MyBigComp";

export default function App() {
  const [store, setStore] = useState({
    a: false,
    b: [],
    c: 0,
    d: true,
    e: { f: [], g: [] }
    // You can have ~20 more in here...
  });

  return (
    <StoreContext.Provider value={{ store, setStore }}>
      <MyBigComp />
    </StoreContext.Provider>
  );
}
```

MyBigComp.jsx:

```
import { useContext } from "react";
import { StoreContext } from "./StoreContext";

export default function MyBigComp() {
  const { store, setStore } = useContext(StoreContext);

  const toggleX = () => {
    const newAState = !store.a;
    setStore({ ...store, a: newAState });
  };

  const addY = () => {
    const newBState = [...store.b, { z: 1 }];
    setStore({ ...store, b: newBState });
  };

  return (
    <>
      <Comp1 a={store.a} toggleX={toggleX} /> // For simplicity I only pass two
      props but in reality there are like 10-12 props for each component.
      <Comp2 b={store.b} addY={addY} />
      <Comp3 c={store.c} toggleX={toggleX} />
      <Comp4 d={store.d} e={store.e} addY={addY} />
    </>
  );
}
```

I think that this is what you need for now, but of course, if you need to improve you code, you can use useReducer hook, for example, or even redux/zustand/jotai or other state manager library.

I hope I had help